# Is there a way to convert an .xml file into .textgrid?

Tags: r, file-conversion

I have time stamped transcripts with 2 different speakers in .xml (created as Adobe Premiere XML file). I would like to turn this into a two-tiered textgrid to work with in Praat, with one speaker in each tier. Ideally, I would like to do this in R instead of Python.

I've seen options for converting textgrids to .xml but not how to go the other direction. Is there another related file type that I could convert into a textgrid?

Comment: The [xml2](https://xml2.r-lib.org/) package reads xml files into R. [textgRid](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/textgRid/) seems to be a textgrid package for R, it might help with the conversion. It might help to include the name of the software that created the XML in your search, XML is a generic file format that can contain any type of content.